# Haskell: Converting a .lua table to Haskell workable types

Tags: parsing, haskell, lua-table

I'm a beginner trying to practice coding haskell by translating some simple repo from different languages to Haskell.

Many simple games use .lua to store character/ability data.

What I want is to take that .lua table and convert it into haskell workable types.

This is what the .lua file looks like

```
local Data =
{
["Weapons"] = {
    ["AB"] = {
        Name = "AB",
        Cost = {
            Spells = 65000,
            BCost = 15000,
            MCost = 150,
            sh = 35,
            Time = 24,
            Parts = {
                { Name = "Top",Type = "Item",Count = 1,},},
        },
        Resist = 0.85,
        Class = "Shield",
        Attack = {
            Damage = {
                ["First"] = 5,
                ["Second"] = 5,
                ["Third"] = 40,},
            Chance = 0.2,
            X = 2,
        },
    },
    ["PG"] = {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}

return Data
```

When woking with Aeson, there's this simple function `decode` which you can use as `decode someJSON :: Maybe Object` and get the entirety of JSON file content put in default Aeson datatypes which you can work on with library functions. I haven't been able to find something similar for `.lua`.

Comment: You may check [hslua-aeson](https://github.com/hslua/hslua-aeson) package. It seems to have instances to push and receive Aeson's Value type to and from the Lua stack.

Comment: @Redu From its README.md it seems like the package does JSON to Lua. Is converting Lua to JSON possible with that package?

Comment: @Redu This is what I tried `main = do
  openlibs

  dofile "src/configfile.lua"
  wData <- getglobal "Data" *> peek (-1)
  liftIO $ print (wData :: Value)
` after removing `local` from the `.lua` file.

Comment: Sorry.. i have no experience with Lua - Haskell workflow at all. It was just an idea. Have you tried going through the [code](https://github.com/hslua/hslua-aeson/blob/master/src/Foreign/Lua/Aeson.hs)?

Comment: No worries! The code you linked does seem to convert Lua table values to Haskell in `Peekable` instance. It might just work! I'll just need to work out how it operates.